# Solving Google Kickstart 2018 round c Q3

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm a newbie to this contest and it is the first time participating. I have two questions to ask.

1. I downloaded input and it has aa.in format (I never saw this kind of format :p). Then should I make output as aa.out format or can I just use aa.txt format? And if I need to make aa.out format, then how can I make it? Just redirect it using > aa.out?
2. I tried to solve this problem (https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=4384486#s=p2) and it worked well for the sample cases but when I submit it is incorrect. At the beginning it showed some negative numbers for some cases which should not happen. Thus, I debugged it not to have them by converting int to long long and put some modular. However, I still can't get the answer while I don't know why. Therefore, I need some help figuring out what's going wrong here. If you give me even a hint, it will be very helpful!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void makeFullArray(unsigned long long * full, unsigned long long arrlen, unsigned long long x1, unsigned long long y1, unsigned long long C, unsigned long long D, unsigned long long E1, unsigned long long E2, unsigned long long F)
{
    unsigned long long  prevx = x1;
    unsigned long long prevy = y1;
    unsigned long long  x, y;
    for (unsigned long long i = 2; i <= arrlen; i++)
    {
        x = (C * prevx + D * prevy + E1) % F;
        y = (D * prevx + C * prevy + E2) % F;
        full[i] = (x + y) % F;
        prevx = x; 
        prevy = y;
    }
}

unsigned long long exponential(unsigned long long base, unsigned long long exp)
{

    unsigned long long res = 1;
    while (exp)
    {
        if (exp & 1)
            res *= base;
        exp >>= 1;
        base *= base;
    }
    return res;// (res % (1000000000 + 7));
}

void getexponential(unsigned long long  * temp, unsigned long long cnt, unsigned long long * result, unsigned long long K, unsigned long long n)
{
    unsigned long long mod = 1000000007;
    for (unsigned long long j = 1; j <= K; j++)
    {
        for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        {

            result[j] += ((temp[i] * exponential(i + 1, j)) % mod);


        }
    }

    printResult(result, K);
}

void calculate(unsigned long long n, unsigned long long * full,  unsigned long long * result, unsigned long long K)
{

    for (unsigned long long i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        unsigned long long multiplier = i;
        unsigned long long cnt = 0;
        unsigned long long temp[102] = { 0 };
        for (unsigned long long j = 1; j < n; j++)
        {

            temp[cnt] = full[j];
            cnt++;

            if (cnt == multiplier)
            {
                //cout << cnt << "  -- " << endl;

                getexponential(temp, cnt, result, K, n); 

                j = j - cnt + 1;
                if (n - j < multiplier)
                    break;

                cnt = 0;

            }
        }
    }

}

unsigned long long getsum(unsigned long long * result, unsigned long long K)
{
    unsigned long long tmp = 0;
    unsigned long long mod = 1000000007;
    for (unsigned long long i = 1; i <= K; i++)
    {
        tmp += (result[i] % (mod));
        tmp %= mod;
    }

    return tmp;
}

int main(void)
{
    int TC;
    scanf_s("%d", &TC);
    for (int i = 1; i <= TC; i++)
    {
        unsigned long long N, K, x1, y1, C, D, E1, E2, F;
        scanf_s("%llu %llu %llu %llu %llu %llu %llu %llu %llu", &N, &K, &x1, &y1, &C, &D, &E1, &E2, &F);

        unsigned long long full[101]; 
        unsigned long long result[21] = { 0 }; 

        full[1] = (x1 + y1)%F;

        // figure out the given array A
        makeFullArray(full, N, x1, y1, C, D, E1, E2, F);
        // calculate for each exponential power
        calculate(N+1, full, result, K);
        // sum over the range K to get the answer
        unsigned long long tot = getsum(result, K);
        cout << "Case #" << i << ": " << (tot%(1000000007L)) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please note that code containing `using namespace std;` and a header such as `#include <iostream>` is inherently C++ code, and not C code.  You should be careful when you tag your question.  Or, if you're under the illusion that you were looking at C code, you are going to have to rethink what's going on and switch gears to C++ — or decide that the information is not helpful to you.

Comment: There are no such things as "aa.txt format" or "aa.in format" or "aa.out format". These are file names. (Almost) all file names are good for everything. You can use any without changing anything else in your program.

Comment: There is nothing like aa.in or aa.out I have cleared 3 round of code jam it just need your answer in a file and read your question from a file that’s it.

Comment: @n.m. thanks for the answer. What I meant is the in/out thing(file format) not aa(the name). When I downloaded the test set it had a file format &quot;.in&quot;

Answer (score 0):

You can download other contestants answers and run them on the same inputs, and see where your answers differ. That might give you some clues.

Comment: Oh I didnt know that. Thanks for the answer!!